# Dart - How to define a property that must be implemented in any classes inheriting?

Tags: dart

If I do this:

```
abstract class Base {
  void doSomething();
}

class Sub extends Base {

}
```

I'll get a warning in my IDE that I haven't implemented `doSomething` in `Sub`. How do I do that same thing for properties. Let's say I have a class like this:

```
class BaseChannel {
  void connect() {
    Socket.connect(topic);
  }
}

class PostChannel extends BaseChannel {

}
```

`PostChannel` hasn't implemented a `topic` property here. Is there a way to do something in `BaseChannel` that signals that `PostChannel` needs to?

Answer (score 4):

If you want all subclasses to implement a `topic` getter, you need to declare one as part of the *interface* of the superclass. Like you can declare an abstract method, you can also declare abstract fields and getters/setters.

Example:

```dart
abstract class BaseChannel {
  String get topic; // Abstract getter declaration.
  void connect() {
    Socket.connect(topic);
  }
}

class PostChannel extends BaseChannel {
  final String topic; // Implements the getter.
  PostChannel(this.topic);
}
```

With Dart 2.12 you will also be able able to declare "abstract fields":

```dart
  abstract final String topic;
```

or (if it needs a setter too)

```dart
  abstract String topic;
```

This will be equivalent with declaring an abstract getter, or an abstract getter/setter pair.

Answer (score 0):

Two options. Separately for getters and setters. It depends on what you need.

```
abstract class BaseChannel {
  String get tipic;

  void set topic(String topic);
}

class PostChannel extends BaseChannel {
  //
}
```

Error:

```
Missing concrete implementations of 'getter BaseChannel.tipic' and 'setter BaseChannel.topic'.
Try implementing the missing methods, or make the class abstract.
```

You will need to implement some of this:

- getter
- setter
- getter and setter
- field

It all depends on what you declare abstract in the base class (getter, setter or both).